# Correct way of creating a large Json string using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I'm using Gson to create a Json string. Up until now, I've been serializing a relatively small classes with a few members, so I just created a class with the needed members and just used `toJson` to create the json. If it's relevant to this question, then its inside an Android application.

Now I need to create a more complex json with many fields and several levels. An example of the json (at least a part of it just to show the "spirit" of it):

```
"sleep" : {
  "program" : {
   "appName" : "name",
   "appVersion" : "1.7"
   "serverVersion" : 19
   },
   "userType" : "new",
   "userInfo" : {
      "firstName" : "Hans",
      "lastName" : "Schmidt",
      "city" : "Berlin",
      "country" : "Germany",
    },
   "settings" : {
      "setting1" : "y",
      "setting2" : "none"
 }
 ...
}
```

In this case, do I need to create a different class for every tree? for example, a class for the "program" part, a class for the "userInfo" and so on and then create a class for the "sleep" root which contains every smaller class as its member and use `toJson` on it? I'm guessing it will work, but is it the most efficient way to create so many classes for a single Json?

Comment: If you want a pojo representation of your json then you'll need different classes for the various tree levels like you suggested. If you don't need that you could probably (I don't know Gson but I'd assume it's very similar to Jackson) also just use a combination of maps/JSONObject instances and lists/JSONArray instances.

Comment: what is the problem, gson will do the job for you ?

Comment: and you can just write classes and implement it with each other then gson will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Maps in order to achieve the goal. In the extreme case (I mean, in the case you don't want to create any classes), if you want to create this json:

```
{
   "sleep":{
      "userInfo":{
         "firstName":"Hans",
         "lastName":"Schmidt",
         "country":"Germany",
         "city":"Berlin"
      },
      "settings":{
         "setting2":"none",
         "setting1":"y"
      },
      "program":{
         "appVersion":"1.7",
         "serverVersion":19,
         "appName":"name"
      },
      "userType":"new"
   }
}
```

You could do:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Map<String, Object> finalObject= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> sleep= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> program= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> userInfo= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> settings= new HashMap<>();

    program.put("appName", "name");
    program.put("appVersion", "1.7");
    program.put("serverVersion", 19);

    userInfo.put("firstName", "Hans");
    userInfo.put("lastName", "Schmidt");
    userInfo.put("city", "Berlin");
    userInfo.put("country", "Germany");


    settings.put("setting1", "y");
    settings.put("setting2", "none");

    sleep.put("program", program);
    sleep.put("userType", "new");
    sleep.put("userInfo", userInfo);
    sleep.put("settings", settings);

    finalObject.put("sleep", sleep);

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(finalObject));
```

But, as said in another answer, often it is recommended to create the POJOs.

**EDIT**

There is another way in order to do this. Using the **JsonObject** class:

```
    JsonObject finalJsonObject= new JsonObject();
    JsonObject jsonSleep= new JsonObject();
    JsonObject jsonProgram= new JsonObject();
    JsonObject jsonUserInfo= new JsonObject();
    JsonObject jsonSettings= new JsonObject();

    jsonUserInfo.addProperty("firstName", "Hans");
    jsonUserInfo.addProperty("lastName", "Schmidt");
    jsonUserInfo.addProperty("country", "Germany");
    jsonUserInfo.addProperty("city", "Berlin");


    jsonSettings.addProperty("setting2", "none");
    jsonSettings.addProperty("setting1", "y");

    jsonProgram.addProperty("appVersion", "1.7");
    jsonProgram.addProperty("serverVersion", 19);
    jsonProgram.addProperty("appName", "name");


    jsonSleep.add("userInfo", jsonUserInfo);
    jsonSleep.add("settings", jsonSettings);
    jsonSleep.add("program", jsonProgram);
    jsonSleep.addProperty("userType", "new");

    finalJsonObject.add("sleep", jsonSleep);

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(finalJsonObject));
```

If you notice that you use always the same code then you should create the classes (in order to improve the mapping and eliminate the repetition). If there are some classes that you use few times, you could use this approach (and avoid to create each classes that you need).

Comment: When its recommended to use the POJOs? Not only if I'm receiving a json representation and need to deserialize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can take two approaches:

1) Create Java classes for each "level", and play with POJO fields. I think this is the correct approach. The GSON serializer is optimized for that, so don't worry about performance.

2) Create the JSON "by hand". This is not recommended, and you won't get any significant performance improvement. Also, you aren't using the power of the POO.

Anyway, if possible, try to organize your data to use as less "levels" as possible, this will definitely help with the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by creating the model classes and a parent class.

FOr example

```
Class Sleep{


hashmap<String,Object> sleep;

//getters and setters



}



Class program{
String appName,appVersion,serverVersion;

// getters and setters;


} 

Class userInfo{
String firstName,lastName,city,country

// getters and setters

}



Main(){

Sleep sleep = new Sleep();

Hashmap<String,Object> sl = new HashMap<>();
sleep.setSleep() = sl;

program p = new program();
p.setappName("name");
p.setappVersion("1.7");
p.serverVersion("19");

sl.put("program",p);

// similarly for the userInfo

new Gson().toJson(sleep);

// This will give you the nested json as you wanted.
}
```